# Excel, sum if a row value matches a vlookup value on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Is it possible to sum all values in a column, based on a criteria checked against on another sheet?

I have two sheets, one with values, one with manufacturers.  I would like check if the manufacturer has any value other than "YES" on another sheet and then sum if not equal to "YES".  The end result is a total for all manufacturers that do NOT have a value of "YES" on Sheet 2.

In the example below I am trying to sum everything EXCEPT for Manuf B, a total of $1,132.

[image]

So far the formula I was working on (non functional) was:

```
=sumif(vlookup(C5:C12,'SHEET 2'!E5:F8,2,false),not("YES"),B5:B12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bit cleaner...

```
=SUM(SUMIF(C5:C12,IF(Sheet2!F5:F8<>"YES",Sheet2!E5:E8,FALSE),B5:B12))
```

It's still an Array Formula so you have to hit **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** instead of just *Enter* when you add the formula

Comment: This works, but I'm not sure I understand why the sum() around the sumif() is required.

Comment: Because the `Sumif` actually returns a value for each criteria, so the `Sum` is needed to get a single value.  See [SUMIFS with multiple criteria and OR logic](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic) for more

Answer (score 0):

As an array formula with CSE,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B5:B12,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C5:C12, TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(F5:F8<>"yes",E5:E8)))))
```

[image]

... or a (possibly) more conventional array formula (with CSE),

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B5:B12, C5:C12, TRANSPOSE(INDEX(E5:E8&IF(F5:F8="yes", CHAR(215), TEXT(,)), , ))))
```

[image]

Slightly abbreviated version of the latter array formula,

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B5:B12,C5:C12,INDEX(IF(F5:F8="yes",CHAR(215),E5:E8),,)))
```

[image]

Comment: so, CSE stands for Crtl + Shift + Enter?